# Is there a way to load ReactJs extension inside CefGlue (windows forms c# application)?

Tags: cefsharp, cefglue

We are trying to load reactjs extension in cefglue chromium. We were able to override cefextensionhandler and were able to use loadextension. The extension successfully loaded message is also received but when we goto developer tools, it does not show.

Do we have any working example with cefSharp / CefGlue to load extensions inside chrome? We are using cefglue in our application.  (the current application is inside office loaded as task panel and works fine for end user.) This is more of a developer's request - who find it useful to use the extension.

Comment: Make sure you read https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1947/add-support-for-chrome-extensions in detail, only a small number of extension apis are supported. It's likely your extension uses apis that aren't supported.

Comment: thanks @amaitland

the page clearly states below.. so do we have an example for the same?

To support the React Developer Tools extension (v2.5.1) we need to add:

chrome.browserAction
setIcon
setPopup
chrome.devtools
inspectedWindow.eval
inspectedWindow.tabId
panels.create
network.onNavigated.addListener
network.onNavigated.removeListener
panels.themeName
chrome.runtime
getURL
connect
onConnect.addListener
onMessage.addListener
sendMessage

Comment: Until someone implements those APIs it's not supported.

Comment: thanks for prompt response, I think we will have to live with what we have.. thanks a lot..